# what kind of jena vocabulary should I use for creating a RDF which is mosly based on ART?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, ontology

I want to create some RDF my problem is I don't know what kind of vocabulary should I use for such thing:

here is a sample of my data (which I have stored them into several XML files)

```
<uri>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Herbie_Mann</uri>
<classtype>classtype:Artist</classtype>
<title>Herbie Mann</title>
<albums>
<album url="/~u0082/intelweb2/%3fq=album/75">Push Push</album>
<album url="/~u0082/intelweb2/%3fq=album/87">At the Village Gate</album>
</albums>
<website>http://www.herbiemannmusic.com</website>
<biography>
Herbie Mann, credited as being one of the seminal jazz flutists, is probably best known for the musical....
</biography>
```

and this is a very sketchy code that I've written :

```
  Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        Property prop = model.createProperty(artistURI);

        Resource herbie_mann = model.createResource(artistURI);
        herbie_mann.addProperty(RDF.value,artistName);
        herbie_mann.addProperty(RDF.object,artistClass);
        herbie_mann.addProperty(RDF.subject , model.createResource().addProperty(RDF.object, artistAlbum1));
        model.write(System.out);
```

but I don't like the idea of using value/object/subject and I want to replace it with something more generic but meaningfull and I don't know how can I do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you have a look at the [Music Ontology](http://musicontology.com/)? It covers exactly what you need, and is already used by major data providers like the BBC.

Jena doesn't have a pre-defined class with constants for the music ontology (like it has for the `RDF` and `DC` and other namespaces), so you can do either of the following:

- Use Jena's [schemagen tool](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/documentation/tools/schemagen.html) to automatically generate a Java class with the constants defined in the Music Ontology
- Create your own constants for classes and properties with `createProperty()` and `createResource()`.